# Request for a copy of a paper of J. Dénes on permutation factorisations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

I'm unable to access the following paper: J. Dénes, The representation of a permutation as the product of a minimal number of transpositions and its connection with the theory of graphs, Publ. Math. Inst. Hung. Acad. Sci. 4 (1959) 63-70. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried requesting it through Inter-Library Loan at your institution?

Comment: There is a paper 
Permutations as Products of Transpositions
George Mackiw
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 102, No. 5 (May, 1995), pp. 438-440
Published by: Mathematical Association of America
Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975036

Comment: Voted to close as "off-topic".  I don't think that MO is the place for this sort of request.

Comment: This might seem like an obvious answer, but if you know anybody in Budapest (or, more broadly, Hungary) they will probably be able to get their hands on it.  I have never been able to find electronic versions of this series from before 1980, but people in Central Europe seem to have volumes around.

Comment: Apologies if this is off-topic, I thought I'd seen others make similar requests on this website in the past and figured it was fine. No success with inter-library loan, and I know no one in Hungary. I guess I'll just have to reconstruct the contents of the paper from those that cite it.

Comment: I will try to find it. I cannot guarantee a success, but I'll try. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *PUBLICATION OF THE MATHEMATICAL INSTITUTE OF THE HUNGARIAN ACADEMY OF SCIENCES* is available online.

http://real-j.mtak.hu/view/journal/A_Magyar_Tudom=E1nyos_Akad=E9mia_Matematikai_Kutat=F3_Int=E9zet=E9nek_k=F6zlem=E9nyei.html

You can download this specific paper here: http://real-j.mtak.hu/510/